# How to use QuantLib with Vs2012

Tags: c++, c#-4.0, quantlib

Has anyone tried the recent version of QuantLib in VS2012 c#?

Is there any C# wrapper available please? My I request steps to compile and use it please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C# wrappers are included in the QuantLib-SWIG package at https://sourceforge.net/projects/quantlib/files/QuantLib/1.4/other%20languages/. They include a VS2012 solution (QuantLib_vc11.sln) in the CSharp folder. Disclaimer: I haven't tried it.

The wrappers assume a working installation of the QuantLib C++ library. Instructions are at http://quantlib.org/install/vc10.shtml (they're for VC++2010, but also work for later versions). Also, you'll have to set the environment variable QL_DIR to the path of your QuantLib installation (e.g., "C:\Programs\QuantLib-1.4") before opening the C# solution.

Comment: Thank you - I've got it running. I am getting an error - negative time (-0.857143) given in the Instrument.HPP - Instrument::performCalculations() --> AnalyticDividendEuropeanEngine::calculate() --> iDividendVanillaOption.NPV()... debugging it, but can't find much information in the debugger mode- new to VC++ environment.

Comment: You're probably better off taking this other problem to the QuantLib mailing list. See https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/quantlib-users